# compute timeseries with values from a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes df_t with columns: id, user_id, timestamp score and df_u with column user_id. A user_id in df_t may be repeated while it is unique in df_u. I want to compute a timeseries for each user_id of length 365, one step for each day of the year 2019. Each timestep needs to have the score of the user_id on that day. In df_t I can have timestamp before and after the 2019 and also there are missing days in 2019, I need to insert this day with a score o -1 on the timeseries.

So this is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_t = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 
                    'user_id': [1, 2, 2, 2],
                    'timestamp': ["2012-01-01", "2019-01-20", "2019-04-03", "2019-05-01"],
                    'score': [1, 3, 3, 4]
})
print(df_t)
df_u = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 2]})
print(df_u)

df_u_expected = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 2],
                              'scores_list':[
                                  ["list of 365 '-1' since it does not have any score in 2019"],
                                  ["-1, ..., 3, ... 3, ..., 4 ..., -1, ..."]
                              ]
})
print(df_u_expected)
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: So is there a question here?

Comment: Yeah, do you have any idea or suggestion that can help me on how to do this? @itprorh66

Comment: This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific problem with code you are writing, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Suggestions lead to opinion based answers which are beyond the scope of this site.